# CSS Not Putting Div Horizontally

Tags: html, css, class

Not sure where the code broke, hoping someone can find something that sticks out. I gave all of the palette elements a div tag of #cpalettes but the only element that received the flex-wrap was the 'primary' group.
As you can see, when it is run, the "Primary" colors show up with the correct spacing between each box. But the rest of the colors on the page are showing up without horizontal spacing, or with too much space between them.
I'm not sure what else to do as I also added a div tag of 'swgp' to apply to each swatch.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Style Guide</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600&family=Playfair+Display:wght@500;600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="col-m">
      <h1>STYLE GUIDE</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="col-m" id="colors">
      <h2>COLOR PALETTE</h2>
      <div id="cpalettes">
        <div class="palette" id="pri">
          <h3>PRIMARY COLORS</h3>
          <div class="swgp">
            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="p1"></div>
              <p id="flabel">#CC5555</p>
            </div>

            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="p2"></div>
              <p id="flabel">#55CCBE</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="palette" id="sec">
          <h3>SECONDARY COLORS</h3>
          <div id="swgp">
            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="s1"></div>
                <p id="flabel">#55CC55</p>
            </div>

            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="s2"></div>
                <p id="flabel">#CC8C55</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="palette" id="ter">
          <h3>TERTIARY COLORS</h3>
          <div class="swgp">
            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="t1"></div>
              <p id="flabel">#B7B7B7</p>
            </div>

            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="t2"></div>
              <p id="flabel">#717171</p>
            </div>

            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="t3"></div>
              <p id="flabel">#000000</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="palette" id="status">
          <h3>STATUS COLORS</h3>
          <div class="swgp">
            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="st1"></div>
              <p id="flabel">#8CF09F</p>
              <p id="flabel">SUCCESS</p>
            </div>

            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="st2"></div>
              <p id="flabel">#FF2929</p>
              <p id="flabel">ERROR</p>
            </div>

            <div class="swatches">
              <div class="swatch" id="st3"></div>
              <p id="flabel">#FF924E</p>
              <p id="flabel">PENDING</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="col-m" id="type">
      <h2>TYPOGRAPHY</h2>

      <div class="tygp" id="playdisplay">
        <div id="fontex">
          <p id="fex">Aa</p>
          <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Medium / #000000</p>
        </div>

        <div id="hex">
          <div>
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Extra Bold / #000000</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Extra Bold / #000000</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
            <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Extra Bold / #000000</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="bodyex">
          <div id="bodycopy">
            <div id="blorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Medium / #000000</p>
          </div>
          <div id="bmisc">
            <div id="binline">
              <p>This is inline text</p>
              <p id="flabel">Playfair Display - Medium / #CC5555</p>
            </div>
            <div id="bbutton">
              <p>This is button text</p>
              <p id="flabel">Playfair Display - Medium / #55CCBE</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tygp" id="open sans">
        <div id="fontex">
          <p id="fex">Aa</p>
          <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Medium / #000000</p>
        </div>

        <div id="hex">
          <div>
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Extra Bold / #000000</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Extra Bold / #000000</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
            <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Extra Bold / #000000</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="bodyex">
          <div id="bodycopy">
            <div id="blorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <p id="flabel">Font family: Playfair Display - Medium / #000000</p>
          </div>
          <div id="bmisc">
            <div id="binline">
              <p>This is inline text</p>
              <p id="flabel">Playfair Display - Medium / #CC5555</p>
            </div>
            <div id="bbutton">
              <p>This is button text</p>
              <p id="flabel">Playfair Display - Medium / #55CCBE</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="col-m" id="icons">

    </section>
  </body>
</html>

body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

section.col-m{
  width: 85vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

section.col-m>h1{
  font-size: 10rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #898989;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 2.5rem 0;
}

section#colors>h2{
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-color: #000000;
}

div#cpalettes{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div#pri,div#sec{
  width: 28%;
}

div#ter,div#status{
  width: 42%;
}

div.palette>h3{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000000;
}

div.swgp{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.swatches{
  width: 50%;
}

div.swatch{
  width: 11.5vw;
  height: 11.5vw;
}

div#p1{
  background-color: #CC5555;
}

div#p2{
  background-color: #55CCBE;
}

div#s1{
  background-color: #55CC55;
}

div#s2{
  background-color: #cc8c55;
}

div#t1{
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
}

div#t2{
  background-color: #717171;
}

div#t3{
  background-color: #000000;
}

div#st1{
  background-color: #8CF09F;
}

div#st2{
  background-color: #FF2929;
}

div#st3{
  background-color: #FF924E;
}
```

Comment: Remove all styles from div.swgp and apply only display: flex and see if it's that you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much Filipe that fixed the issue. I really appreciate it.